# Moved to another server and some things stopped working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a webpage that was working fine on my VPS, I moved it to another VPS and some things on the page stopped working like the "clipboard.js" and the glyphicon icons. I can not figure out why. It's a one page website, and they are not php related to make me think that I am missing a php extension.

Below is my head section of the page. I am using cdns for eveything.

```
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/language/en_US.min.js"></script>

    <!-- for phone number! -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-formhelpers/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.css" integrity="sha256-v8+xOYOnVjQoSDMOqD0bqGEifiFCcuYleWkx2pCYsVU=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-formhelpers/2.3.0/js/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js" integrity="sha256-H7Mu9l17V/M6Q1gDKdv27je+tbS2QnKmoNcFypq/NIQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <!-- for copy to clipboard -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.6.0/clipboard.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

Comment: what do you see in console?

Comment: Perhaps it are the settings of your cdn account, you might need to add your new domainname to it